# Kubernetes - Ingress network policy from other pod

Tags: kubernetes

I have 2 servcies running in same namespace. Both are working fine as expected. Now, trying to connect serviceB( Label is app: serviceB ) from serviceA(  Label is app: serviceA ).  Hence, added ingress policy in serviceB as follows to allow traffic from serviceA.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1 
kind: NetworkPolicy 
  metadata:   
     name: serviceA-whitelist 
  spec:  
   podSelector:
     matchLabels:
       app: serviceB   
   ingress:
   - from:
     - podSelector:
         matchLabels:
           app: serviceA
```

Still, it is not working. I tried, log into serviceA as,

> kubectl exec -it serviceA-podname bash

**NC Command**

> nc -v -w 2 serviceB 8444

Getting connection timeout.

Am i missing anything?

Comment: By default, all pods allow all traffic, did you do anything to deny all by default? Additionally you might need to allow Service A egress to Service B.

Comment: We did deny all by by default at cluster level.

Comment: It works after adding egress also.

Comment: please post your solution for completeness of your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It started working fine after adding the egress policy with the source.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1 
kind: NetworkPolicy 
  metadata:   
     name: serviceB-egress-policy
  spec:  
   podSelector:
     matchLabels:
       app: serviceA   
   egress:
   - to:
     - podSelector:
         matchLabels:
           app: serviceB
```

Answer (score 0):

As [itaysk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/310298/itaysk) wrote, all traffic should be allowed by default except for created rule to deny all by default. The problem was with egress traffic: ingress was allowed and egress was denied. After adding the rule to egress, all was stabilized.